# ASP.NET TABLE + INSIDE A Scrollable DIV, + Table Cell Position:Relative : ModalPopupExtender

Tags: html, css, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have a asp.net table inside a scrollable div. I have created a matrix table in which the leftmost table cell acts as a fixed column by using CSS `Position:relative`. Now I have a `ModalPopupExtender` Over that table. When I am trying to open that on the left most cell (the cell which is relative) by clicking on it, the left cell disappears.

How can I click the cell keeping it relative?

I sincerely appreciate the help.

Comment: could you add the makeup code? I think I know what is causing the problem, it's probably with the way you nested your cells, but i would be sure only if you post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you for the interest shown in answering.

I figured out the solution just now. Opened the link and saw your message pasted 8 hours back.

Solution:

1. Add following style to the column

   ```
   table.mytable tr td.myfirstfixedcolumn
   {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0px;
    min-height:14px;
    min-width:55px;
   }
   ```
2. Add a Table Cell underneath the fixed column with same dimensions in order to make some space for the remaining columns to appear normally. I called it placeholder and applied the following styles to it

   ```
   table.mytable tr th.placeholder
   {  
    margin-top:-1px;
    min-height:14px;
    min-width:55px;
   }

   table.mytable tr td.placeholder
   {
    min-width:55px;
   }
   ```